# VML background image positioned on bottom for Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, vml

I am creating an email which has to be look good on Outlook. On the email, I have a paragraph of text (which heights amounts to 324px), and I need a background image (height: 153px) located on the bottom of the paragraph.

I now have the below codes:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" background="background.png" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:bottom;background-size: contain;" height="324" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 620px;height: 153px;">
        <v:fill type="frame" src="background.png" color="#ffffff"  />
      <![endif]-->
      Body Text here
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
    </td>
```

The current problem is:

1. The background image is not to scale. It's stretched to the full height of the paragraph.
2. I'm not sure how to position it on the bottom of the paragraph.

Can anyone good at VML help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I ask.... Why are you using a background image which is only going to sit below the text anyway? Why not just a normal inline image?

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein, because part of the image needs to be below the text

Comment: Hmm, someone else may have a positioning fix for this but ultimately a lot of the time, it's hard to find a consistent result across Outlook and all other email clients, when you fiddle with positioning like this. Looking at how this is working, it may be a case of you having to supply an alternative image for Outlook, that includes  blank space above the image.

Comment: Going with @Digital_Frankenstein on this. If you want to fit an image to a cell, you need the image to be the same height of the cell. Reason being if you give a VML a specific height, the rest of the content above the assigned height will not be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to think outside the box on this one ;)

Option (A), create the background image with the required height, as per [Syfer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744111/vml-background-image-positioned-on-bottom-for-outlook#comment103802992_58744111)

Option (B), Put most of the content above the VML, and only a couple of lines in the VML part. That way the VML part won't stretch, but you'll still get the effect, i.e.:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" background="background.png" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:bottom;background-size: contain;" height="324" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<p>Body text here</p>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 620px;height: 153px;">
        <v:fill type="frame" src="background.png" color="#ffffff"  />
      <![endif]-->
      Part of body Text here
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use aspect, position and origin attributes on v:fill. That sort of simulates background: center bottom contain from css:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" background="background.png" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:bottom;background-size: contain;" height="324" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 620px;height: 153px;">
        <v:fill origin="0,0.5" position="0,0.5" aspect="atmost" type="frame" src="background.png" color="#ffffff"  />
      <![endif]-->
      Body Text here
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
    </td>
```